# Не могу развернуть .NET Core на Linux под nginx

Tags: c#, .net, nginx, .net-core

Всем привет. Развернул .net core app на Ubuntu 16.04.
Установил и настроил обратный прокси-сервер на прослушку 80 порта на порт 5000.
При загрузке через интернет меня перенаправляет почему-то на 5001 порт.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из launch убрал 5001, оставил только "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000".
Вот default от nginx.

```
server {
listen        80;
server_name   195.133.145.155;
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

}
Заметил, что прямо на машине если гружу http://localhost:5000, то меня редиректит на 5001, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: `server_name   example.com *.example.com;` - должен быть ваш домен

Comment: @aepot у меня нет домена. на сайт заходят по ip. вписать ip туда?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41751491/12888024

Comment: @aepot Я изменил домен на ip, однако ничего не изменилось. Я сделал правку в вопросе, можешь посмотреть как именно я описал конфиг выше.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь вопрос на уроне приложения, которое запускается в kesterl. Если посмотреть лог Network в Chrome и там будет видно, кто отдаёт команду на редирект с 80-го порта http он отправляет на 5001 порт https. Согласно документации https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio в продуктиве (release сборка) отрабатывает перенаправление на https. Проверьте использование  `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` И лучше настроить nginx на использование 443 порта и https.

Подробная документация как готовить .NET за обратным прокси здесь
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: ничего нет в логе. 195.133.145.155 - ip

Comment: Ок, по логам я вижу, что с 80-го порта http он отправляет на 5001 порт https, то есть это всяко проделки kestrel.
Согласно документации (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) В продуктиве (release сборка) отрабатывает перенаправление на https. Проверьте использование     `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` И лучше настроить nginx на использование  443 порта  и https

Comment: Вообще, при использовании обратного прокси нужно ещё дополнительно  добавить в код несколько строчек. Подробная документация как готовить .NET за обратным прокси здесь (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Я по этой статье и дэплоил. Все строки я добавил.

Comment: app.UseHttpsRedirection(); уже используется у меня(.

Comment: Заметил, что прямо на машине если гружу http://localhost:5000, то меня редиректит на 5001, в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Решением стало удаление строки app.UseHttpsRedirection();
Она указывалась в туториале от Microsoft. Расскажите нужно ли ее использовать, если я не собираюсь подключать SSL?

Comment: Не нужно……………..